# Query builder API is giving 0 results in publish, But the /libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html console is giving proper result

Tags: aem

I am using Query builder API in java code to get pages with a particluar tag, In all environments its is giving a proper result, But in one of the environment it is giving 0 results in publish,We cross verified the permissions also. Not sure why this is happening.
But the /libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html console is giving proper result.

Comment: Can you run the debug level logging on query api (instructions on the querydebug.html page) and see if something comes up?

Comment: We have found the solution for it, I tried Running the Querydebug.html, it gave me proper result. We fixed it by giving permission to etc node and specific child nodes. Earlier we missed giving permission to etc node(but gave read permission to child nodes).

Answer (score 1):

We have found the solution for it,
I tried Running the Querydebug.html, it gave me proper result.
We fixed it by giving permission to etc node(root node) and specific child nodes.
Earlier we missed giving permission to etc(root node) node(but gave read permission to child nodes).